# SQLite Lua Library

Tags: sqlite, lua

Looking for a good SQLite Lua library. I found [LuaSQLite3](http://lua.sqlite.org/index.cgi/dir?ci=tip) but trying to figure out how to use it in Lua. I've created DLL's to expose functions to Lua before with RakNet (a networking library), but can't see how this SQLite would work. This seems to be setup to compile for non-Windows machines and I would need it for Windows. I can create a DLL but not following how it works.

The examples that come with it simply say require("lsqlite3") at the top of the files, but I don't know where that Lua file is. The C code would create the DLL that I would expect that lsqlite3 would load in because I'm pretty sure `require()` doesn't load a DLL as when I did my RakNet DLL I had to use `package.load()` I believe it was. So lsqlite3 must be a Lua file, but I don't see it in the downloaded package. Maybe I'm blind :)

Any ideas?

I pulled the C source file into a new Visual Studio Express 2010 DLL project. Brought in Lua source and sqlite source and compiled the DLL. That worked all well and so I have a lsqlite3.dll file. When I put `require("lsqlite3")` in my Lua project I get an error from Lua saying it can't open the file. The file is in the same dir as my lua interpreter.

Comment: Ah nvm. The code doesn't have the export code so the DLL is blank. bah.

Comment: OK that didn't work. Still stuck now as to why it's not working.

Comment: The error message you get from Lua will show all the places Lua searched for the DLL. What does it say?

Comment: The easiest way to get lsqlite may be to use LuaRocks; however, you will need to have an SQLite DLL on your path somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You will find some useful examples here: http://barracudaserver.com/ba/doc/en/lua/luasql.html

Have fun!